# Why can't lasers cut shiny surface and reflect?

Tags: reflection, laser

A laser can cut hard material but why it reflects and don't cut the shiny surface for e.g. a mirror. Shouldn't it cut a mirror also as it is powerful and cuts hard substances.

Comment: Not all lasers are the same, differing in both frequency and intensity, and used for different purposes.

Comment: You _do_ know that a "laser beam" is a beam of _light,_ right? And you know what mirrors do with light?

Comment: P.S., The fact that a laser "can cut hard material," is one reason why people sometimes choose a laser cutter, but "hardness" has nothing to do with the reason why a laser can cut. Laser cutters work equally well on soft materials.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes I know about both but I have seen that laser don't cut a mirror, and they do reflect them, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: OK, so, what is your question? Are you asking why some surfaces reflect light? Are you asking why some surfaces reflect certain wavelengths of light? Are you asking whether any laser cutters are made that operate at a wavelength that would be suitable for cutting a typical glass mirror? some other kind of mirror?

Comment: I've certainly managed to blow up a few laser mirrors...

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes yes you got it. I think my answer would be in  why some surfaces reflect light and some not and whether any laser cutters are made that operate at a wavelength that would be suitable for cutting a typical glass mirror?....

Comment: @JonCuster really? I thought laser would just reflect the glass and not cut it

Comment: @HitmanA7 - even high power laser mirrors have power maximums. And something like scattering off of a dust particle can lead to very high local power, and once a defect is formed in the (often very complex) optical coating power absorption increases dramatically.